# How to cache a piece of GSP with per HTTP session and with timeout?

Tags: grails, caching, gsp

I am using Grails 2.2.0 GSP's asynchronous include like this:

```
<g:include action="asyncAction" />
```

Question: how to cache content generated by "asyncAction" a) for certain amount of time, b) per user's session? Without writing a custom tag.

---

I forced clients to cache "asyncAction", but Chrome/Firefox keeps requesting it each time:

```
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=1600, public")
```

Wrapped the include with a `<cache:block>` provided by Grails "cache" plugin - got it cached per application and forever. It's not customizable at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<g:include action="asyncAction" />
```

calls the `asyncAction` action and adds the output to the page. So if you install the cache plugin, you should add the `@Cacheable` annotation to this action

```
@Cacheable('someCache') 
def asyncAction() {

}
```

then in `Config.groovy` specify the timeout of the cache named `someCache`

```
someCache {
    name 'someCache'

    timeToIdleSeconds 60 * 60  // item will be removed if not requested at least this often
    timeToLiveSeconds 60 * 120 // item will be always be removed after this period
}
```